# ¿ Por qué se da ix is not iterable?

Tags: lista, pandas

Estoy probando un código que construí junto a otra persona, en su pc funciona correctamente y en mi pc, me origina el error `ix is not iterable`. Lo diferente del código eran nuestras rutas hacia los archivos.

Al ser una gran cantidad, se creó una lista primero de los nombres de los archivos para después pasar la ruta, respecto a nuestros sistemas operativos utilizamos Linux Fedora.

Cambié y oculté algunos nombres por mantener la confidencialidad de lo que estoy realizando.

```py
for px in lis:
    a="/../../../../../.."+px+".out"
    sp= pd.read_table(a[0],header=None,skiprows=532,delim_whitespace=True,names=['lambda', 'fobs', 'fsync', 'w', 'errf'])
    fnorm=pd.read_table(a[0],skiprows=25,nrows=1,header=None,delim_whitespace=True)

    fnorm=float(fnorm[0])
    sp.fobs=fnorm*sp.fobs
    df_merge = pd.merge(f606,sp, left_on='x',right_on='lambda')

    m606=sum(df_merge.y*df_merge.fobs)
    m606=-2.5*np.log10(m606*1e-16/o606)
    F606W.append(m606)

    df_merge = pd.merge(f475,sp, left_on='x',right_on='lambda')
    m475=sum(df_merge.y*df_merge.fobs)
    m475=-2.5*np.log10(m475*1e-16/o475)
    F475W.append(m475)
```

```
 for spaxel in lis:

  File "/usr/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py", line 117, in __iter__
    raise NotImplementedError("ix is not iterable")

NotImplementedError: ix is not iterable
```

Comment: ´´´ for spaxel in lis:

  File "/usr/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py", line 117, in __iter__
    raise NotImplementedError("ix is not iterable")

NotImplementedError: ix is not iterable'''

Comment: eso parece ser un error del modulo de pandas

Comment: ¿ Que se puede hacer? ¿ Actualizar la librería?

Comment: puedes actualizarla o desinstalarla y volverla a instalar

Comment: Reintalé y me aparece el mismo error

Comment: lo siento, no sé que mas podrías hacer

Comment: Imposible saberlo sin entender como se llega a `for spaxel in lis`, estas pegando un código que es bastante posterior al error, necesitamos entender como se construye y para que se usa el objeto  `lis`.

Comment: El error no se encuentra en el código que has adjuntado, ya que la variable "ix" no aparece. Pero lo que te está diciendo el error es que estás intentado iterar por un objeto que no es iterable, para iterar en Python necesitas que sea una colección iterable (lista, tupla, etc). Un error de este tipo se puede reproducir así ```for i in 5: print("hola")```

Comment: El objeto lis, es simplemente una lista que debe completar la accion, por ejemplo spec112.out. El objeto lis contiene el 112.               Lo que debe hacer con ese archivo son las acciones que siguen en las siguientes líneas de codigo y así con todos los objetos de la lista